# Instance property remains nil after non-nil assignment

Tags: ios, swift

***The short version***

In the following code excerpt, I am assigning the value of `cell`, a non-nil variable, to `popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView` which remains `nil` after the assignment:

```
    guard let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? HoleTableViewCell else {
        return
    }
    print("Cell number " + String(describing: cell) + " selected")
    popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = cell
    print(String(describing: popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView))
```

The two print statements produce the following two lines:

```
Cell number <Eclectic_Boogaloo.HoleTableViewCell: 0x7fde340a3000; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 374 69); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x60400003e140>> selected
nil
```

Why would the second `print` statement return a nil value?

***The long version***

I have a `UITableView` called `Holes Table` which contains custom cells of the class `HoleTableViewCell'. Within the cell is a button which, when selected, programmatically calls a popover. The full code for the button is as follows:

```
@IBAction func selectParValue(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Retrieve the cell containing the selected button
    guard let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? HoleTableViewCell else {
        return
    }

    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "parPopover") 

    print("Cell number " + String(describing: cell) + " selected")
    popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = cell
    print(String(describing: popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView))
    popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = cell.bounds

    popOverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    popOverVC.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self

    present(popOverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

However, at run-time, I get the following error because the `sourceView` on the popup view controller is nil:

`2017-12-31 18:39:27.670140+0000 Eclectic Boogaloo[10333:1091992] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController (<UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x7f9ed6552200>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'`

Comment: Try setting the `sourceView` and `sourceRect` after setting the `modalPresentationStyle`.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you, @maddy.  Do you know why this should work in this way?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simply to set the `modalPresentationStyle` before that of the `sourceView` and `sourceRect`.

Thanks to @maddy for this tip.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `popoverPresentationController` is `nil` until you set the view controller's `modalPresentationStyle` to `.popover`.

So you need to move the attempts to set `sourceView` and `sourceRect`.

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "parPopover") 

popOverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = cell
popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = cell.bounds

popOverVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self

present(popOverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```